# Jquery Ui Tabs Reload a tab in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am new to jquery and am using jquery Ui tabs. I'd like to refresh the contents of a tab on button click.

I am able to refresh the contents but when I click on the button again after refreshing the page, the call is sent twice or the number of times refresh took place. How can I resolve this. Some of my code:

```
   <script>
      function LoadRightsDialog(templateID,projectId) {
    $('#RightsConfig').load('/Template/ConfigRightsprojectId='+projectId+'&templateId='+templateID)
    }
    </script>

     <div id="tabs" style="border:none;padding-top:0;margin-top:0" >
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#RightsConfig"><span>Rights</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#GenConfig"><span>General</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="RightsConfig" style="height:100%">
            @Html.Partial("ConfigRights",@Model.Item2,null)
        </div>
    <div id="GenConfig">
//some code
</div>
</div>
```

I am calling the javascript function from an iframe in the `RightsConfig` Tab

Comment: Are contets you load every time the same? or they are loaded by some parameters ?

Comment: No they are updated each time not same some things in the contents are same thought, actually when I click on the ajax action link to render a Modal Dialog the call is sent twice..

Comment: maybe `LoadRightsDialog` was invoked twice somewhere?

Comment: NO that isn't the issue

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I found out that the reason behind the issue was that the jquery files were being referred twice in the partial view as well as the Main view where the divs were being created this was causing the trouble